# Customize evtoggle in Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to create a button using Snap.svg. I have been looking at the demos and examples from [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/05/animated-svg-icons-with-snap-svg/) about animated svg icons. A few other sources also cover the basics of how to do this, but the issue that I am stumped at is: Is there a way to trigger the animation explicitly(I don't want to attach it to any typical events like click or mouseover, rather I want to trigger the animation when something happens in my code, like when a boolean variable is set to true.)? Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm just call the animation whenever you want to then, instead of from the click handler ? It sort of depends when your 'boolean' gets set to true and if you can do it there with an if statement. If you can show some code on a fiddle it will help.

Comment: Oh, you are right I could do that too. I was thinking of more like a callback that I could bind to a variable. I was over thinking this problem. My bad!